# What kind of variable is "&[Page]" in VB?

Tags: vba, environment-variables

Today I discovered the expression `"&[Page]"` in some old VB code. It seems to hold a pagenumber in case some document would get printed. I (VB novice!) didn't know this existed but it did help me out seriously today! So I wonder whether there are more such "hidden" variables. Where can I find an overview?

I thought this is an "environment variable" or a "system variable" but Googling these seems to suggest that `"&[Page]"` belongs to neither category.

Comment: "&[Page]" is a string constant. Maybe it's being inserted into some other tool that can make sense of it. Post some code to give it context. That string constant doesn't mean anything in VB.

Comment: @AakashM and ElectricLlama: I'm actually using SaxBasic (basically VB within SPSS). A tiny example that's incredibly useful is [this piece of code](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/116120595/%40diff_footers_15.sbs) that inserts a string with the page number into every page of an output doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are **Header and Footer elements**.
From the Header and footer tools (image from excel 2010):

[image: Header and footer tools]

Click this button to:

- Page Number: Insert the `&[Page]` code that puts in the current page number.
- Number of Pages: Insert the `&[Pages]` code that puts in the total number of pages.
- Current Date: Insert the `&[Date]` code that puts in the current date.
- Current Time: Insert the `&[Time]` code that puts in the current time.
- File Path: Insert the `&[Path]&[File]` codes that put in the directory path along with the name of the workbook file.
- File Name: Insert the `&[File]` code that puts in the name of the workbook file.
- Sheet Name: Insert the `&[Tab]` code that puts in the name of the worksheet as shown on the sheet tab.
- Picture: Insert the `&[Picture]` code that inserts the image that you select from the Insert Picture dialog box that shows the contents of the my Pictures folder on your computer by default.
- Format Picture: Apply the formatting that you choose from the Format Picture dialog box to the `&[Picture]` code that you enter with the Insert Picture button without adding any code of its own.